# Infinite loop with image.onload and image.onerror

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to load and image and if the url is not valid, put an error image instead. In my case the onerror event seem to be called infinitely:

html:

```
<div id="output"></div>
```

javascript:

```
function createImage(imageId) {
    var spinnerUrl = 'http://placehold.it/600&text=spinner';
    var errorUrl = 'http://placehold.it/600&text=error';
    var successUrl = 'http://placehold.com/600&text=success';
    var img = new Image();
    img.onerror = function() {
        console.log('no image at url: ' + imageId);
        this.src = errorUrl;
    };
    img.onload = function() {
        this.src = successUrl;
    };
    img.src = spinnerUrl;   
    return img;
};

function loadImage(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).appendChild(createImage('image-id'));
};

loadImage('output');
```

you'll notice that the log displays 'no image at url: image-id'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you re-assign the `successUrl` repeatedly in your `onload` callback, causing infinite recursion because it gets called over and over again.

To solve, update the `onload` callbacks:

```
img.onload = function() {
    this.onload = function() {
       // Whatever you want to do now.
    };
    this.src = successUrl;
};
```

(The same with the error callback).

In general, I don't think this is a clean way of doing it. I would simply create multiple `Image` objects to avoid confusion (and possibly preload the spinner with the page). Allocating `Image` has only tiny overhead and almost never matters.

Comment: I don't really understand why the onload in the onload prevents the inifinite loop and that second onload is basically empty. Ugly but its works

Comment: When you re-assign `src`, it will trigger another image loading for the same Image object. Once that image (the success or error image) is loaded, it would call the same `onLoad` again! This would re-assign the same string, which however causes the image to be reloaded again .. (no matter the string is the same). Hope that helps!

Comment: got it, makes sense now :D